# ExtJs BufferedStore fetching descending by id

Tags: javascript, extjs, infinite-scroll

I have REST service with some data:

```
[{id:20},{id:16},{id:14},{id:11},{id:9},{id:8}]
```

---

request (get data with id less then 15)

```
?fromId=15&count=3
```

response

```
[{id:14}, {id:11},{id:9}]
```

---

request (no fromId means get last data)

```
?count=3
```

response

```
[{id:20},{id:16},{id:14}]
```

---

Is there any way to use BufferedStore with this API (I use it with gridpanel)?
The main question is how to make store requests with descending fromId.

**UPD**:
I have to get infinite scrollable grid panel with this data. But have no idea how to configure proxy and store for it.
Is it possible or I should override some methods to fill request manualy?

**UPD Store:**

```
Ext.define('Admin.store.OrderStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.BufferedStore',
model: 'Admin.model.Order',
alias: 'store.order',
autoLoad: true,
autoDestroy: true,
remoteSort: true,
remoteFilter: true,
proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    url: 'api/order',
    limitParam: 'size',
    startParam: 'fromId',
    extraParams: {
        filter: {}
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'data',
        totalProperty: 'total'
    }
}
```

});

Comment: can you add the code for your store?

Answer (score 0):

Set the [pageSize](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.data.BufferedStore.html#cfg-pageSize), this will limit the number of rows (size in your case) to request from the server. it will jump in 30 for every request.

you can also set a buffer with the property [leadingBufferZone](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.data.BufferedStore.html#cfg-leadingBufferZone)

```
Ext.define('Admin.store.OrderStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.BufferedStore',
    model: 'Admin.model.Order',
    alias: 'store.order',
    autoLoad: true,
    autoDestroy: true,
    remoteSort: true,
    remoteFilter: true,

    pageSize: 10,
    leadingBufferZone: 20,

    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: 'api/order',
        limitParam: 'size',
        startParam: 'fromId',
        extraParams: {
            filter: {}
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'data',
            totalProperty: 'total'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Store should decrease fromId value for every request. In first request it should be null, in second should be equal to last element id and so on.

Comment: startParam should not used as filter, you need to add filter to the store that will be supported in the server.

Comment: bufferedStore should be use in the right way, not sure if you are trying to use it for the right purpose